# Python set: fill with odd numbers

Tags: python

I have following assignment:

Create a **set called 'c' with all the odd numbers less than 10**.

I create the set manually:

```
c={'1', '3', '5', '7', '9'}
```

How can I create this set by a formula so that it would also be feasible with a larger scale?

Thank you for you help?

Comment: Hint: have you been taught the `range` function yet? With 3 arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Use `range`, like this:

```
c = set()
for i in range(1, 10, 2):
    c.add(i)
print(c)
```

Comment: It's could be written in single line: `set(range(1,10,2))`.

Comment: That's also true.

Comment: Also with `c = {i for i in range(1,10,2)}`